# Spring Reactive Web Framework Client

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I was experimenting with reactive web framework.I have certain question regarding how it will work.

In typical application,we have datastore(Relational or No SQL).
Application Layer(Controllers) to connect to store and get the Data.
Client Layer(Calls your API End Points) and get the data.

To best of my knowledge,there are no async or reactive drivers published by Vendors.Only Mongo and may be Cassandra has reactive drivers).
Controller layer will beam back the data using Mono or Flux or Single.

Client layer will be consuming this data.

Since HTTP is synchronous in nature,how will client layer or application benefit from reactive support in Spring.

Question:Let us says I have 10 records in JSON coming from my Flux response.Does it mean,my client will get data in stream or entire data set will be fetched first at client side and then process of consuming it will be reactive in nature.Currently ,we have **InputStream** as a response of service call,which is blocking in nature,due to design of HTTP protocol.

Question:Does it then make sense to have reactive architecture for typical web application,when very medium on which we are going to get response is Blocking in Nature.

***Spring Web Reactive makes use of Servlet 3.1 non-blocking I/O and runs on Servlet 3.1 containers. It also runs on non-Servlet runtimes such as Netty and Undertow. Each runtime is adapted to a set of shared, reactive ServerHttpRequest and ServerHttpResponse abstractions that expose the request and response body as Flux with full backpressure support on the read and the write side.***

Source:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html

Answer (score 2):

Datastore vendors and OSS communities are working on that. There's already support for Cassandra, Couchbase, MongoDB and Redis in Spring Data Kay.

I think you're conflating the HTTP protocol itself and blocking Java APIs. You're not getting the full HTTP request or response in one big block, so the HTTP procotol is not synchronous. The underlying networking library you choose also drives the choice between blocking or non-blocking I/O.

Now about your HTTP client question: if you're using `WebClient`, the returned `Flux` will emit elements as soon as they're available. The underlying libraries are reading and decoding messages as soon as possible, while still respecting backpressure.

I'm not sure I get your last question - but if you're wondering when and why you should use a reactive approach: this approach has benefits if you're already running into scalability/efficiency issues, or if your application is communicating with many external services and is then sensitive to latency. See more about that in [the Spring Framework 5.0 FAQ](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-5-FAQ#why-are-we-introducing-spring-webflux).